# What is preferable way to say the phrase "changeble weather"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives, synonyms

I'd like to know what is the best way to express the situation when the weather changes very often  in American English and in British English. For example: "The weather is changeble/irregular/fluid/capricious in spring here."

Comment: I'm not aware of any single best word. There are a lot of ways to express this concept. Words I would be tempted to use (in American English) are *unpredictable*, *erratic*, *fickle*, *finicky*, or even just *crazy*. Most of these have pretty negative connotations, though. You could also say something like *variable* or *highly variable*.

Comment: "Unpredictable" is a way to describe weather which is also rather ironic in that meteorologists do their best to predict the weather as accurately and as long-term as they possibly can. :-)

Comment: "Unsettled" is also used, though it generally refers to a relatively short period of variability vs a more established condition.

Comment: Strictly speaking "changeable weather" is the preferable way (to spell it at least) :o)

Comment: How about just "weather"? There are only a handful of places where the weather is so consistent that you really need the qualifier. :)

Answer (score 3):

I like the phrase "fickle weather" and use it myself for this exact purpose, but it's perhaps a bit more literary than saying "changeable weather", which also works well and will be understood by everyone (whereas 'fickle' is a lower frequency word than 'changeable' and it's not obvious what it means from its root). "Unpredictable weather" also works, but that technically doesn't mean it's changing a lot, just that you or the weather stations are having trouble forecasting what it's really going to be like.

Comment: *Fickle* would be understood by any native US English speaker.